# ValueError: Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ganache, brownie

I am using Brownie and added a Ganache local network using the following command:

`brownie networks add Development ganache-local host=HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545 cmd=ganache-cli`

After compiling, I try to deploy the smart contracts with `brownie run token.py  --network ganache-local` Then, I get the following error:

```
TokenProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 45, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "brownie/network/web3.py", line 68, in connect
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'
```

I did some digging and found this in the source code:

```
if self.provider is None:
    if uri.startswith("ws"):
        self.provider = WebsocketProvider(uri, {"close_timeout": timeout})
    elif uri.startswith("http"):
        self.provider = HTTPProvider(uri, {"timeout": timeout})
    else:
        raise ValueError(
                    "Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket "
                    "beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'"
                )
```

Does this mean I have to set a provider (like Alchemy) for my local network? Does that even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of struggling, passing the `network_id=5777` argument solved my problem. Apparently, brownie cannot recognize the local network created in the Ganache app without this argument.